# Twitter bootstrap datetime-picker not showing properly in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have been using twitter bootstrap datetime-picker with ruby on rails for showing the calendar, also I am using this in a modal, but it shows as partial, because I am trying to show at the bottom of the screen

**HTML**

```
 <div id="datetimePicker" class="input-append date">
     <input data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text" id="testdate"></input>
     <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#datetimePicker').datetimepicker(); 
 });
</script>
```

also I have used this additional css

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
 z-index:99999 !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the screenshot? Maybe there is a need to tweak the CSS.

Comment: this is the same thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267787/bootstrap-datetime-picker-showing-in-modal-as-partial

Comment: looks like model-body has overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your  Input field id on datepicker.

please do not write tag on your.JS file.

```
$(function() {
     "use strict";
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#testdate').datetimepicker(); 
     });
   });
```

Or you can add direct below code on your .html file

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#testdate').datetimepicker(); 
 });
</script>
```

Please also check from your browser firebug plug-in , twitter bootstrap datepicker javascript loading or not ?

Hope it will works :)

Comment: actually that js directly put in the html file for testing, thats why i used like that

Comment: NO worries, have you check with your input field id , it is working?

Comment: yes checked,but its not working, actually its showing in a modal, and the datetimepicker put end of that modal, so when click on that, it will show the partial part of calendar, the other part we can't see that.

Comment: are you using this datepicker, https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker ?

Comment: ok, there may be something missing, bootstrap datetime picker javascript loading ?