# Bootstrap datetime picker in Modal mode not appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetime, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to implement a datetime picker of bootstrap in modal view such as this screenshot below:

[image]

My code is as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                &times;
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="H3">Add New Overtime</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='ot_date'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Enter OT Date" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='ot_timein'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter OT Time-in"/>
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class='input-group date' id='ot_timeout'>
                                    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Enter OT Time-out" />
                                    <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                Close
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Save
                            </button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ot_date').datetimepicker();

    $('#ot_timein').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: true
    });

    $('#ot_timeout').datetimepicker({
        language: 'en',
        pick12HourFormat: true
    });
});
```

I have checked the following links but still no definite answer.

[Query1 - DateTime picker in bootstrap is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28529183/datetime-picker-in-bootstrap-is-not-working)

[Query 2 - Twitter bootstrap datetime-picker not showing properly in modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264409/twitter-bootstrap-datetime-picker-not-showing-properly-in-modal)

[Query 3 - Bootstrap datetime-picker showing in modal as partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27267787/bootstrap-datetime-picker-showing-in-modal-as-partial)

Comment: check whether you are getting any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks a lot to **@Guruprasad Rao** for giving me an idea whats missing in my code. There I found in the console that Moment.js is needed first before calling the bootstrap-datetimepicker.js. So you can download [the Moment.js from here.](http://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker)

In my code, I implemented, as follows:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/plugins/datetimepicker/js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/plugins/datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

**REMINDER:** Moment.js MUST be called first before datetimepicker.js

Secondly, thanks a lot to **@Melvas**. I salute you men. Thanks for correcting my code. As you said, the ID="ot_date" is added in the input element NOT in the DIV. Great mind...

So implementing the two changes I mentioned above, I got this screenshot below.
The calendar now works as expected.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want initialize picker for this element:  $('#**ot_date**').datetimepicker().
But it is a 'div' element, not input. Try to change your HTML as:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" id="ot_date" placeholder="Enter OT Date" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"> 
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
        </span>
     </div>
 </div>
```